# Caption content's opacity not setting to 1 on slide

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a caption with text and buttons in it that when you hover over the image it appears. Now the caption I have set to appear at .7 opacity and it seems the text and buttons etc seem to inherit that opacity rather than appear as 1. opacity. I know that setting the child to 1. will still make it 100% of the parent's .7 so it'll be just that; .7. So I need a viable css way off changing this. 
Here's a fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/dottsie/tvdefhom/1/

```
<header>
            <h1>Caption Hover Effects</h1> 
</header>

            <ul class="grid cs-style-1 cs-style-2">

           <li>
               <figure>
               <img src="http://www.ruggit.dk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/_/m/_mg_9746_1.jpg" alt="img04">
                <figcaption> 
                    <h3>Rug1</h3>
                    <span>Mario</span>
                    <a href="http://google.com">buy</a>


                                           </figcaption>
```

Comment: @Adrift Does that change it or has it still been answered? I couldn't find a viable answer for my problem.

Comment: Did you see the `rbga()` recommendation? Does using that instead help?

Comment: I must be blind, just saw them there. I'll give that a go in a while and see if it works. Thank you :)